# Dynamic regression in R Forecasting Package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a time series of two variables representing two currencies: SYP (Syrian pound) and LBP (Lebanese pound). The data represent the daily values of both currencies over the previous six months. I previously run a standard regression model using SYP as dependent variable and LBP as independent variable. This are the results:

```
SYPts <- ts(SYP_LBP)
modelSYPLBP <- tslm(SYP ~ LBP, data = SYPts)
summary(modelSYPLBP)



Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -835.77100  228.93013  -3.651 0.000319 ***
LBP            0.41801    0.02744  15.235  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 324.9 on 248 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4834,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4814 
F-statistic: 232.1 on 1 and 248 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, when I try to run a dynamic regression model using the auto.arima call from the forecast package I obtain:

```
model <- auto.arima(SYPts[, "SYP"], xreg = SYPts[, "LBP"], stationary = FALSE)
summary(model)


Series: SYPts[, "SYP"] 
Regression with ARIMA(0,1,1) errors 

Coefficients:
          ma1   drift     xreg
      -0.4654  5.6911  -0.0163
s.e.   0.0591  3.3376   0.0315

sigma^2 estimated as 9744:  log likelihood=-1495.39
AIC=2998.78   AICc=2998.94   BIC=3012.85

Training set error measures:
                      ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE    MASE
Training set -0.06985184 97.92004 46.45812 -0.1826244 1.792092 1.18404
                    ACF1
Training set 0.001792873
```

The coefficient of the regression is now negative and a lot smaller than the one obtained using the standard regression model.

Furthermore, when I try the forecast with the model assuming 0 change in the LBP over the next 15 days I obtained a quite flat forecast curve and, since the coefficient estimate is negative, the curve becomes flatter and then negative as I increase the forecast values of LBP.

I would like to ask:
1- Did I do some specific error in treating the data and preparing the model? For example, I did not put any frequency of the time serie. Should I?
2 - Should I intervene further on the data by differentiang them before creating the model? In the formula I used STATIONARY = FALSE as if I use STATIONARY = TRUE I obtain very low p-value in the checkresiduals test.
3 - I don't understand if I do something wrong in generating the forecast values for the independent variable (LBP). In the formula `forecast <- forecast(model, xreg = rep(10000,15))`  I assume that the two arguments of rep represent respectively the additional value of LBP and for how many days I want it to be repeated in time. As 10000 was the latest value of LBP in the time series, by using it I assume no change intervene over the next 15 days. Is it correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(This is a very brief answer, just to complete the thread, and in case someone chances upon this question again).
Check your residuals from the tslm() regression for autocorrelation "checkresiduals(modelSYPLBP))".  (Please look up "?checkresiduals" for the interpretation).  If the tests indicate (as is quite likely with time series regressions) that the regression residuals are autocorrelated, then inference based on the coefficient estimates are not valid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).